# Firefox becomes invisible after suspension on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: firefox

Everytime that I suspend my computer, when I return, after a few moments, the Firefox windows becomes invisible and I have to restart the browser. It only happens with Firefox.

[Firefox window invisible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5C4L.jpg)

Edit: I'm using Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Please edit your question to advise which version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: @Graham Done! I forgot to add before :|

Comment: I'm not a user of 19.10 so unable to comment with confidence except as to say with version 18.04 if minimed, FF remains up and running which you can detect from the flag against it on the (in your case) top bar. Clicking on the flagged icon restores it to the place where it was when minimised.

Comment: I have a similar problem but with Chrome (very... slow... window... refreshes... until... I... restart... it...). Using the Nvidia driver on Kubuntu 19.10. What is your video driver?

Comment: @xenoid I'm using a Geforce 1050 TI with the 440.64 driver. But I don't It is the nvidia driver because this only happens with Firefox, the other windows stays normal.

Comment: "Nouveau" or "nvidia" driver?

Comment: @xenoid Nvidia, the proprietary one. :)